# AWS Amplify: How to resend code when Auth 'signIn' API returns 'UserNotConfirmedException'

Tags: react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an unconfirmed aws cognito user which did not verify his email during registration process. When he tries to login with following code:

```
Auth.signIn({
    username:email,
    password:password,
})
```

the API returns

> 'UserNotConfirmedException'

Now at this point the user is unauthenticated, there is no current session or current user. How will this user be able to verify himself and get himself logged in?

`'verifyCurrentUserAttribute'` and `'resendSignUp'` APIs do not work for unauthenticated user.
Please help.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry! not yet.

Answer (score 2):

Late response but just saw this: The `Auth.resendSignUp(<username>)` does not need an authenticated user and is suited for this purpose. It accepts a username parameter as a string and when called will send a new code to the method configured in Cognito.

Answer (score -1):

The right API endpoint for confirming a signup is **confirmsignup**

See : https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#confirmsignup

This endpoint requires an email address and the code. The user can thereby confirm his signup later with the code he has received.

Comment: The op knows how to confirm the password, the issue is how to resend the confirmation code. This code expires after 24 hours, so how does the user confirm with an expired code?